# Kafka-Python consumer (non ending loop) to save the messages as .csv format

Tags: python, csv, apache-kafka

## Cannot save as .csv format in the kafka consumer for the messages produced in kafka producer

I have a python producer with the following configuration:

```
producer=KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],api_version=(0,10,1))
for i in range(10):
    message= "The value is {}".format(i)
    producer.send(topic='test',value=message.encode('utf-8'))
```

And, consumer with:

```
consumer= KafkaConsumer('test',bootstrap_servers=["localhost:9092"],group_id='my-group',api_version=(0,10,1),value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))

csv_file_path="Entries"
with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for message in consumer:
        message_value = message.value
        print(message_value)
        consumer.commit()
        csv_writer.writerow(message_value)
```

what i need is that whatever the kafka producer sends the message to the consumer it has to be save d as csv format.But the issue here is that that the for loop inside the (with open) keeps on running even there is no messages in the producer. Due to this csv is not generated. (Note: i am not sure whether the explained issue for not generating csv is correct)

I need to save the entries sent from the producer in the consumer as a .csv format.